# Understanding how to show continuity for this function on $[2, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm fairly new to epsilon-delta proofs, so please bear with me. I want to show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $[2, \infty).$ I was wondering whether I should break this up into two cases or not. The first case being at $x = 2$ and the other case being at $x > 2$. What I have tried so far is the case when $x = 2$:

I observe that
$$|f(x)-f(2)|= \frac{|x-2|}{2|x|}.$$
Let $\epsilon > 0.$ I take $\delta = \min\{1, 2\epsilon\}.$ Then, since
$$|x-2| \geq ||x| - |2|| \geq -(|x|-|2|) = |2|-|x|,$$
we have that $|x| > 1 \implies \frac{1}{|x|} < 1.$ Therefore
$$|x-2| < \delta \implies \bigg|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}\bigg| = \frac{|x-2|}{2|x|} < \frac{|x-2|}{2} < \epsilon.$$
Is this correct? If so, For the case when dealing with a number, say $y$, greater than $2$, should I just approach it the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited to add more details.

Fix $x\in [2,\infty)$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and put $\delta=4\epsilon$.

If $y\in [2,\infty)$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$

then: $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\frac{x-y}{xy}|\leq \frac{\delta}{4}=\epsilon$$.

As correctly pointed out by OP,  the last inequality follows from: Since $x,y\in [2,\infty)$,  $\frac{|x-y|}{|xy|}=\frac{|x-y|}{xy}$.
So as $xy\geq 4$, we must have $\frac{|x-y|}{xy}\leq \frac{|x-y|}{4}$.

Comment: To break this down... $\frac{|x-y|}{2x} < \frac{4\epsilon}{2\cdot2}$, since $x, y \geq 2$. Right?

Comment: @SomeDude yes. correct